# Find latest data from certain ids in an array then update it

Tags: mysql

The following code is to update a page based on the latest thread a board with many forums has. Basically, I want to find the latest thread (based on time from the table 'topics') in each forum and then update it in another `table('forums')` to be displayed later. There more to this code but I have put the basic element. My problem is how do you search a table for x but only from certain ids? I also do not want it to be a resource intensive venture especially where there may be thousands of rows.

```
$forums=1,2,3; // the forum ids

$DB->query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE forum_id IN($forums) order by last_post DESC"); // get all columns from 'topics' in 1,2,3 BUT I only need the latest ('last_post' of each)

$News = $DB->fetch_row();

$DB->query("UPDATE forums SET  last_title='" . $News['title'] ."' WHERE id IN($forums)");
```

Sorry if this sounds confusing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, considering that `'x'` is in `forum_id` column,

```
$DB->query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE forum_id IN($forums) AND forum_id ='x' order by last_post DESC ");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I do not understand this part "AND forum_id ='x'" what would X be if the array is $forums?

Comment: From here: $forums=1,2,3; // the forum ids - we are searching topics where forum_id is 1,2,3 get only the latest post of each forum_id

Comment: ok, so can you tell me what are you searching for in `$forums` or what is `x` or what did you mean by `My problem is how do you search a table for x but only from certain ids?`

Comment: What I understand from that you are looking for a value say `x` in $forums.

Comment: Basically, topics has a list of messages. Each message has a date (last_post) and a forum id number ($forums). What I want to get is the most recent message (just one based on last_post) from each forum id number ($forums) so I can update it.

Comment: So it might be like: "topic name, 2, this date", then the next would be "topic name, in forum 3, this date", etc.